# Gridview that is bound to sqldatasource in edit mode is not updating a checkbox column in rowupdating event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am using c# and VS 2008.  My GridView has several cells but only one cell ("Active", boolean) with a checkbox TemplateField is not updating in Edit mode when Update button is clicked. I have specified 2 primary keys as DataKeyNames in GridView1 properties. I am using rowupdating event to pass the desired checkbox (bit)value to sqldatasource.  Is there another event I am missing in order to make the update happen? Again, all other cells update just fine.

I did a lot of research before posting here and I still couldn't see where my mistake is.  I only included pertinent parts of the code (gridview properties, the one field in question

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    DataSourceID="sqldatasource1" 
                    onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
                    onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
                    onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
        DataKeyNames="ID,CertID" ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound" 
        onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbActiveEdit" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Active").ToString().Equals("Yes")) %>'
                    Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Active").ToString().Equals("Yes")) %>'
                    Enabled="True" 
                    AutoPostBack="false"></asp:CheckBox> 

                </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label  ID="lblActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Active").ToString().Equals("Yes")) %>' Enabled="false"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldatasource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SomeConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SelectRecords" 
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        UpdateCommand="UpdateRecords" 
        UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlvwRecords" Name="ID" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CertID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CertNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DueBy" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Completed" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Expires" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Renewed" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Comments" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PeriodEffective" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CeuEarned" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Active" Type="Boolean" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C#

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   try
    {

    //Get the new values to Update
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("cbActiveEdit");

    string strActiveStatus;

    if (cb != null && cb.Checked == true)  
        {   
            strActiveStatus = "1";
        }
        else
        { 
            strActiveStatus = "0";
        } 
    sqldatasource1.UpdateParameters["Active"].DefaultValue = GetStatus(strActiveStatus).ToString();//GetStatus is returning “true” or “false”
    sqldatasource1.Update();

    //Reset the edit index.
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    GridView1.DataBind(); 

    }//end try

    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //handle error here 
    }  

}

 protected bool GetStatus(string str)
{
    if (str == "1")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key ingredient missing was this line of code:

```
e.NewValues["Active"] = GetStatus(strActiveStatus);
```

My sqldatasource is using a stored procedure to UPDATE. Apparently `e.NewValues` is needed when passing a custom value to a sqldatasource using a stored procedure.